# Can I integrate database with my selenium python script

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am having a scenario where first i will hit an API to get all the data and add that data in my selenium python script. But before this I want to automatically run my script whenever there is a entry in my data base.Means write now I am manually running my script I want to run it automatically every time when there is a new entry in my database. 
API I am using is basically the entry in the database. So the flow is First there is an entry in DB about user, This entry I will get in a API form and whenever there is an entry My script should get run using the API.

Below is my selenium script

```
import time
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

base_url="https://www.fitotouch.com"
base_url1= "https://www.fitotouch.com/qitouch"
qty: int=2
cart_value : int = 1
driver = webdriver.Chrome('E:/Chrome driver/chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
#function of our 'driver' object.
driver.implicitly_wait(10) #10 is in seconds
driver.get(base_url)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys("*****")
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('arrow-icon').click()
data = requests.get('http://110.93.230.117:1403/api/order/5e439b7052fcf2189ccb5207').json()
print(data)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
time.sleep(2.4)

#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/a/span').click()
time.sleep(2.4)
driver.get('https://www.fitotouch.com/account/login/create')
time.sleep(2.4)
driver.switch_to.frame("accountFrame")
time.sleep(2.4)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/input').send_keys(data['FirstName'])
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/input').send_keys(data['LastName'])
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/input').send_keys(data['Email'])
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div[3]/div/input').send_keys("*****")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/div[4]/div/input').send_keys("*****")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div/button').click()
driver.get("https://www.fitotouch.com/fitoki/f-001-jing-fang-bai-du-wan")
#product_category=['driver.get("https://www.fitotouch.com/fitoki/f-001-jing-fang-bai-du-wan")','driver.get("https://www.fitotouch.com/soria-chinasor/style-02-hzewl")']
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 150)")
time.sleep(2.4)
cart = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/main/article/section/div[2]/div/section/article/section[1]/section/div/div[3]/div/div')

if qty > 0:

  for i in range(qty):
   cart.click()
   time.sleep(2.4)
  # print("quantity was" +qty)

else:
 cart.click()

 url = driver.current_url
 print(url)
```

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? Which line? Error?

Comment: No i am not stuck, I just want to link my this script with the database entry. Write now it is working fine when I am manually executing it. Is it possible to execute it on the entry in database

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the best solution but what comes to mind is that you'd need to have the script running constantly on a while loop. Outside of the loop set a variable which represents the latest row index in the table.

Every x seconds perform a count on the number of rows in the table you're expecting an entry and then if the number of rows exceeds your previously set variable, run your function to go get whatever data. Finally, update your last row variable with the new value.

```
last_row = 10  # example that there are currently 10 rows in the DB table
while True:
    # query database for number of rows "SELECT count(id) from table"
    result = db.fetchone()
    if result > last_row:
        get_data()
        last_row = result
    time.sleep(10)
```

This solution would mean your script is always running but only doing the data collection when you get a new entry in your DB